# List comprehension equivalent in Kusto

Tags: kql, azure-resource-graph

I recently started to use the Azure Resource Graph Explorer to obtain resource information. KQL is a new thing I'm figuring out along the way, and one of the problems I need help with is a means to manipulate an array of dictionaries into just an array of string values.
As an example:

Consider the following data

```
{
  "customerId": "201",
  "orders": [
    {
      "dept": "/packaging/fruits"
    },
    {
      "dept": "/packaging/vegetables"
    }
  ]
}
```

With the following query:

```
Customers
| where customerId == 201
| project customerId, orders
```

The result would be as follows:
[image: firstresult]

My question is, how can I modify the query to produce the following result:
[image: desiredresult]

Tried to go through the KQL documentation, but can't seem to find the correct method to achieve the above. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

in Kusto, you could use `mv-apply`:

```
datatable(customerId:int, orders:dynamic)
[
  201, dynamic([
    {
      "dept": "/packaging/fruits"
    },
    {
      "dept": "/packaging/vegetables"
    }
  ]),
  201, 
  dynamic([
    {
      "dept": "/packaging2/fruits2"
    },
    {
      "dept": "/packaging2/vegetables2"
    }
  ])
]
| where customerId == 201
| mv-apply orders on (
    summarize orders = make_list(orders.dept)
)
```

| customerId | orders |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | [ "/packaging/fruits", "/packaging/vegetables" ] |
| 201 | [ "/packaging2/fruits2", "/packaging2/vegetables2" ] |

In ARG, `mv-apply` isn't supported, so you can use `mv-expand`:

```
datatable(customerId:int, orders:dynamic)
[
  201, dynamic([
    {
      "dept": "/packaging/fruits"
    },
    {
      "dept": "/packaging/vegetables"
    }
  ]),
  201, 
  dynamic([
    {
      "dept": "/packaging2/fruits2"
    },
    {
      "dept": "/packaging2/vegetables2"
    }
  ])
]
| where customerId == 201
| extend rn = rand()
| mv-expand orders
| summarize orders = make_list(orders.dept) by rn, customerId
| project-away rn
```

| customerId | orders |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | [ "/packaging/fruits", "/packaging/vegetables" ] |
| 201 | [ "/packaging2/fruits2", "/packaging2/vegetables2" ] |